# Center root of forest tree

Tags: forest, root

In an assignment for school I require making a lot of trees and large ones too. I searched for some methods and stumbled upon the package forest which has helped me a lot. I'm almost done but couldn't figure out one last essential thing. I want to center the root node of my tree. I center my tree already but it centers the center of the tree rather than the root node too. I'm looking for a way to center the root node specifically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\scalebox{1}{
\begin{forest}
for tree={
parent anchor=south,
child anchor=north,
l=2cm 
}    
[ {[?,?,?,?]}, calign=center
    [ {[Intel,?,?,?]}
        [ {[i7,?,?,?]}
        ]
    ]
    [ {[?,Radeon,?,?]}
    ]
    [ {[?,?,4GB,?]}
        [ {[Intel,?,4GB,?]}
        ]
        [ {[?,Radeon,4GB,?]}
        ] 
        [ {[?,?,8GB,?]}
        ]
        [ {[?,?,4GB,Asus]}
        ]
    ]
]    
\end{forest}
}
\end{center}  
\end{document}
```

The root node [?,?,?,?] is positioned a couple of centimeters to the left of the center of the page whereas the tree as a whole is in the center.

Comment: Welcome! Please can you complete your code so that we can copy-paste-compile it?

Comment: What is the point of the `\scalebox`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend this. For me, it produces an overfull box and, even if it doesn't in this case, it very likely will in others. Moreover, the tree will not *look* centred if it is asymmetrical.

But you can, if you so wish do it:

[image: centred root]

The dashed blue line is just to show the centre of the page.

The centring is achieved using an empty, undrawn node as the root of width `\linewidth`. The visible root is then aligned with the real root, which puts it dead centre.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]% this is just to show the centre of the page
  \draw [dashed, draw=blue!50!white] (current page.north) -- (current page.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{center}
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      if level=0{
        text height=0pt,
        text width=\linewidth,
        inner sep=0pt,
        outer sep=0pt,
        parent anchor=north
      }{
        parent anchor=south,
        child anchor=north,
        align=center,
        if level=1{
          l=0pt,
        no edge,
        }{
          l=2cm
        },
      },
    },
    [
      [{[?,?,?,?]}
          [{[Intel,?,?,?]}
              [{[i7,?,?,?]}
              ]
          ]
          [{[?,Radeon,?,?]}
          ]
          [{[?,?,4GB,?]}
              [{[Intel,?,4GB,?]}
              ]
              [{[?,Radeon,4GB,?]}
              ]
              [{[?,?,8GB,?]}
              ]
              [{[?,?,4GB,Asus]}
              ]
          ]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

In this particular case, because the node anchors are centred, as [Sašo Živanović points out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278708/center-root-of-forest-tree/278793?noredirect=1#comment671409_278793), a simpler version is possible using `minimum width` rather than `text width` and applying to the existing root node. The will make vertical alignment with other document elements simpler but will [fail if `parent anchor` is not centred](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278708/center-root-of-forest-tree/278793?noredirect=1#comment671419_278793).

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{forest}% simplified with Sašo Živanović's suggestion (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278708/center-root-of-forest-tree/278793?noredirect=1#comment671409_278793)
    for tree={
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      align=center,
      l=2cm,
      if level=0{
        minimum width=\linewidth,
        inner xsep=0pt,
        outer xsep=0pt,
      }{},
    },
    [{[?,?,?,?]}
        [{[Intel,?,?,?]}
            [{[i7,?,?,?]}
            ]
        ]
        [{[?,Radeon,?,?]}
        ]
        [{[?,?,4GB,?]}
            [{[Intel,?,4GB,?]}
            ]
            [{[?,Radeon,4GB,?]}
            ]
            [{[?,?,8GB,?]}
            ]
            [{[?,?,4GB,Asus]}
            ]
        ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{center}
```

Comment: An excellent idea, setting the root node's width to `\linewidth`! (Much easier than the solution I wanted to propose.) But why not just set `minimum width=\linewidth,inner xsep=0,outer xsep=0` to the (original) root node and be done with it?

Comment: @SašoŽivanović I thought if I did that that the child anchor would be in the wrong place, so that the edges to its children would not start at the right place.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović Oh, yes. OK. I see. Thank you. I was thinking in terms of `text width` for some reason. Didn't occur to me to use `minimum width`. No idea why. Are you posting an answer or should I simplify mine?

Comment: Actually, my "simplification" to your answer indeed does not work if the parent anchor is not (vertically) in the center, e.g. if it's `north east`. So, looking more generally, your worry is a good one.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović I've added it as an edit. If you'd rather post it as a separate answer, I would be happy to roll back the edit. I thought it would be useful to provide it as it may align better vertically so may be a good solution when the parent anchors are centred.

Comment: No it's good! Actually, I will post the answer I have originally envisioned, as I have just now realized it can be used to center *any* node in the tree. Plus, it shows off v2 ;-)

Comment: I've avoided posting anything which requires the new version ;).

Comment: Hmm ... on second thought, you're right. I'll post it after it's officially out there. Less confusion this way.